# Index out of range in for loop

Tags: c#

So I am working on a game, aside from a game engine, and I have a for loop to detect collisions with all objects in a list of Panels

Here is the code:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 2; x++)
{
    if (player.obj.Bounds.IntersectsWith(walls[x].Bounds))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("COLLIDING");
    }
}
```

Currently there are only two objects added to the list called walls
And everytime I go to run it tells me `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index` I don't know what to do, am I setting up the if statement wrong?

I just tried taking it out of the for loop and replaced x with 0, and when I touched that object it said I was colliding, so I know I didn't set up the if statement wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may or may not know, arrays start at 0 in the index, so your array should be like so.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) 
{
    if (player.obj.Bounds.IntersectsWith(walls[x].Bounds)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("COLLIDING");
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get an error when I do that

Comment: Did you remember to have `x < 2` instead of `x <= 2` ? How long is the walls[] array?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 1):

If there are 2 objects in walls the loop needs not go to x = 2

```
  for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            if (player.obj.Bounds.IntersectsWith(walls[x].Bounds))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("COLLIDING");
            }
        }
```

As Arrays start at index 0

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements in the `walls[]` array means they ware located in `walls[0]` and `walls[1]`( Since .Net arrays are following `0` based indexing) and hence `walls[2]` is out of bound; So you should start the loop with `0` to get the first element and loop up to `2`. **But i strongly recommend you to use length of  `walls` instead of `2`**

```
for (int x = 0; x < walls.Length; x++)
{
    if (player.obj.Bounds.IntersectsWith(walls[x].Bounds))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("COLLIDING");
    }
}
```